# How to fix this quiz game looping problem?

Tags: java

I'm working on a school project quiz game and I have some problems with looping. It only has 5 questions because im just testing on how to make this work. After answering the fifth question, it loops back to the second question, making me answer the questions again. This loops thrice before continuing to the results screen. Is there any way to fix this or should I just use if else instead of switch? I have tried using (questions[i]) instead but it's just showing the first question

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int score = 0;
    int correct = 5;
    
    System.out.println("QUIZ GAME");
    System.out.println("5 points per correct answer. Reach 20 to pass.");
    
    String questions[] = {"\nWhat is the age of the earth?", "How did Hitler die?", "What year did World War II Start?", "Who invented the airplane?", "What are the names of the Atomic Bomb the US dropped on Japan?"};
    System.out.println("There are five questions.");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: 
            {
                System.out.println(questions[0]);
                System.out.println("1. 9000 Years");
                System.out.println("2. 2400 Years");
                System.out.println("3. 4.2 Billion Years");
                System.out.println("4. 500 Million Years.");
                int choice1 = sc.nextInt();
                
                if (choice1 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice1 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice1 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    score = addition(score, correct);
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice1 == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
        
            }
                case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("\n\n" + questions[1]);
                System.out.println("1. Died of old age.");
                System.out.println("2. Executed on 4th of May, 1945 by guillotine on Paris, France.");
                System.out.println("3. Killed on action.");
                System.out.println("4. Suicide.");
                int choice2 = sc.nextInt();
                if (choice2 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice2 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice2 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice2 == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    score = addition(score, correct);
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
            }
            case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("\n\n" + questions[2]);
                System.out.println("1. 1939");
                System.out.println("2. 1935");
                System.out.println("3. 1931");
                System.out.println("4. 1942");
                int choice3 = sc.nextInt();
                if (choice3 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    score = addition(score, correct);
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice3 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice3 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice3 == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
            }
            case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("\n\n" + questions[3]);
                System.out.println("1. Thomas Edison");
                System.out.println("2. Wilbur and Orville Wright");
                System.out.println("3. Marie and Pierre Curie");
                System.out.println("4. Albert Einstein");
                int choice4 = sc.nextInt();
                if (choice4 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    score = addition(score, correct);
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice4 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    score = addition(score, correct);
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice4 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice4 == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
            }
            case 4:
            {
                System.out.println("\n\n" + questions[4]);
                System.out.println("1. Skinny Woman and Little Girl");
                System.out.println("2. Yeet and Yikes");
                System.out.println("3. Fat Man and Little Boy");
                System.out.println("4. The Big One and The Small One");
                int choice5 = sc.nextInt();
                if (choice5 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice5 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    score = addition(score, correct);
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice5 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    score = addition(score, correct);
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                else if (choice5 == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong.");
                    System.out.println("Score = " + score);
                }
                
                
            }
            int fin = 1;
            
            if (score >= 20)
            {
                System.out.println("You passed! Congratulations!");
            }
            else if (score > 20)
            {
                while (fin != 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("You failed! Do you want to do it again? [y/n]");
                    fin = sc.nextInt();
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

public static int addition(int x, int y)
{
    int total = x + y;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Try using debug tool or print out the various variables

Comment: There is no obvious point in your outer loop. You switch on the loop variable; you may as well just have the code blocks in sequence.

Comment: You forgot to `break` out of your cases. Also (slightly off-topic), there is no point in defining trivial methods like `addition()`. It's far easier to read `score += correct;` than `score = addition(score, correct);`

Comment: There are tons of ways you can simplify your code. for instance: if ( answer == 4 ) { // correct } else { // right } don't add identical else blocks to clutter up your code. Also make it dynamical: don't hardcode what the right answer is.

Comment: You need a `break` at the end of every `case`. Else, you fall through all the other cases.